# Can matlab hardware support packages be installed to the 2016a matlab runtime?

Tags: matlab

I am attempting to build an app that will make use of the ADALM 1000 hardware support package and will run on a 2016a runtime platform.
Can this be done?

Can a support package be installed to the 2016a runtime?

Answer (score 0):

Upon running the App Compiler I found that it had recognized the need for the ADALM1000 support package from the App code and included the support in the build.
I installed the Matlab 2016a runtime on a PC that was not running Matlab and found that the hardware support had indeed installed with the newly compiled App.

This will be very useful if you are building apps to drive some supported gadget.